# Postgresql: find hashed indexes

Tags: postgresql, wal

I am setting up WAL-archiving and streaming replication to a warm standby server with Postgresql 9.1.

The Postgresql documentation states:

> Operations on hash indexes are not presently WAL-logged, so replay
>   will not update these indexes. This will mean that any new inserts
>   will be ignored by the index, updated rows will apparently disappear
>   and deleted rows will still retain pointers. In other words, if you
>   modify a table with a hash index on it then you will get incorrect
>   query results on a standby server. When recovery completes it is
>   recommended that you manually REINDEX each such index after completing
>   a recovery operation.

How can I find out if a specific database contains hash indexes?

Answer (score 3):

Check [pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/catalog-pg-class.html) and [pg_am](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/catalog-pg-am.html) to find indexes using the hash method:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pg_class
    JOIN pg_am ON pg_am.oid = relam
WHERE   relkind = 'i'
AND     amname = 'hash';
```